# ¿Por qué cuando intento insertar un SVG con la etiqueta <img> esta desaparece?

Tags: html, css, display

Estaba utilizando una imagen con formato SVG para el logo de una página web. Al principio todo iba correctamente y la imagen se mostraba, pero luego esta desapareció. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

```
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav id="nav-mobile">
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined">menu</span>
                <div class="container-logo">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="resources/logo.svg" alt="logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Leí por ahí que era un problema de display o del escalado de la imagen, a lo que intenté usar css para poner todas las cajas del mismo tamaño; pero aún así la imagen seguía en el mismo estado.

```
* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
    color: black; 
}

.container-logo {
    display: flex;
    width: 20%;
}


.container-logo a {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.container-logo a img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

¿Alguna idea de lo que pueda hacer?

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que utilizas flexbox sin necesidad y eso hace que el enlace dentro de `.container-logo`, a efectos prácticos, tenga unas dimensiones de cero píxels. Eliminando el `display: flex;` de dicha clase, ya funciona. De hecho, puedes prescindir del código de `.container-logo a` y `.container-logo a img` y verás que también funciona igualmente.

Te recomendaría que, tratándose de un logo, definieses unas dimensiones fijas para la etiqueta `img`.

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

.container-logo {
    /*display: flex;*/ /* Esta línea es la que genera el problema */
    width: 20%;
}

/* Estos dos estilos de aquí abajo también son prescindibles al completo */

.container-logo a {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.container-logo a img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-logo">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Tux.svg" alt="logo">
  </a>
</div>
```